# Open find and replace dialog in the IDE

Tags: vba, ms-access

Is there any way to open the **Find and Replace** dialog in the Access VBA IDE programmatically? To be clear, not F&R on a form or control but in the code window itself? Access doesn't have `SendKeys` and I can't find any command to do it.

Reason I ask is I have an ultrawide monitor and the dialog always opens in the top left of the screen. I'd like to use WinApi's `SetWindowPos` to reposition it as I use F&R a lot in my current project. I'm considering rolling my own function using VBE Extensibility but checking here first for a quick solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of, but you could check out [MZ-Tools](https://www.mztools.com/).

Its *Find/Replace* window at least opens where you left it:

[image]